# Large size kmalloc in the linux kernel kmalloc

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am looking at Linux version 4.9.31

And a kmalloc() function of slab and slub

The following is the kmalloc() function of include/linux/slab.h

```
static __always_inline void *kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    if (__builtin_constant_p(size)) {
        if (size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
            return kmalloc_large(size, flags);
#ifndef CONFIG_SLOB
        if (!(flags & GFP_DMA)) {
            int index = kmalloc_index(size);

            if (!index)
                return ZERO_SIZE_PTR;

            return kmem_cache_alloc_trace(kmalloc_caches[index],
                    flags, size);
        }   
#endif
    }   
    return __kmalloc(size, flags);
}
```

In the above code, kmalloc_large() is called when __builtin_constant_p(size) is true.

**First question.** What is the relationship between __builtin_constant_p(size) and kmalloc_large()? Should not kmalloc_large() be called in runtime, not compile time?

The following is the __kmalloc() and __do_kmalloc() of mm/slab.c

```
static __always_inline void *__do_kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags,
                      unsigned long caller)
{
    struct kmem_cache *cachep;
    void *ret;

    cachep = kmalloc_slab(size, flags);
    if (unlikely(ZERO_OR_NULL_PTR(cachep)))
        return cachep;
    ret = slab_alloc(cachep, flags, caller);

    kasan_kmalloc(cachep, ret, size, flags);
    trace_kmalloc(caller, ret, 
              size, cachep->size, flags);

    return ret; 
}

void *__kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    return __do_kmalloc(size, flags, _RET_IP_);
}
```

The following is the __kmalloc() of mm/slub.c

```
void *__kmalloc(size_t size, gfp_t flags)
{
    struct kmem_cache *s;
    void *ret;

    if (unlikely(size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE))
        return kmalloc_large(size, flags);

    s = kmalloc_slab(size, flags);

    if (unlikely(ZERO_OR_NULL_PTR(s)))
        return s;

    ret = slab_alloc(s, flags, _RET_IP_);

    trace_kmalloc(_RET_IP_, ret, size, s->size, flags);

    kasan_kmalloc(s, ret, size, flags);

    return ret; 
}
```

**Second question.** Why do slub __kmalloc() check "size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE" and call kmalloc_large() at runtime ?

Answer (score 2):

Your two question are actually parts of the single question:

> What is __builtin_constant_p(size)?

Operator `__builtin_constant_p` is gcc-specific extension, which checks whether its argument can be evaluated at *compile time*. E.g., if you call

```
p = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL);
```

then the operator returns true.

But with

```
size_t size = 100;
p = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
```

the operator returns false*.

By knowing that some function's parameter is known at compile time, one may check it at compile time, and perform some optimizations.

```
if (__builtin_constant_p(size)) {
    if (size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE)
```

While `size > KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE` seems to be runtime-check here, it is actually compile-time check, because outer condition garantees that `size` is known at compile time. With that knowledge, compiler may optimize out inner branch, if it is false (if the branch true, compiler may optimize out other branches).

E.g.,

```
p = kmalloc(100000, GFP_KERNEL);
```

will be compiled into

```
kmalloc_large(100000, GFP_KERNEL);
```

and

```
p = kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL);
```

will be compiled into

```
__kmalloc(100, GFP_KERNEL);
```

But

```
size_t size = 100000;
p = kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
```

will be compiled into

```
size_t size = 100000;
__kmalloc(size, GFP_KERNEL);
```

because compiler cannot predict the branch at compile time.

Implementation of "fall-back" function `__kmalloc` checks its parameters anywhere, for the case when compile-time checks cannot be performed.

---

*- in my recent tests compiler actually doesn't try to predict value of `size` variable which has been assigned directly with a constant. But this may be changed in future gcc versions.

Comment: I understand your explantion. thanks. But the second question is why is it possible to call kmalloc_large() only at slub at runtime? Is it OK to check the "size < KMALLOC_MAX_CACHE_SIZE" and put a routine that calls kmalloc_large() in the slab ?